# rails 3.1.3 has_many/belongs_to fixtures are not equal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assume two models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

and their associated fixtures:

foos.yml:

```
one:
  ...
```

bars.yml:

```
one:
  foo: one

two:
  foo: one
```

And then a testcase:

```
test "fixtures equal?" do
  foo = foos(:one)
  assert_equal foo, foo.bars.first.foo
end
```

This test fails for me in both the unit test framework and the functional test framework.   The failure I get looks like:

```
1) Failure:
test_fixtures_equal?(FooUnitTest) [test/unit/foo_test.rb:53]:
<#<Foo id: 980190962, created_at: "2012-05-18 21:47:27", updated_at: "2012-05-18 21:47:27">>
with id <70029939109360> expected to be equal? to
<#<Foo id: 980190962, created_at: "2012-05-18 21:47:27", updated_at: "2012-05-18 21:47:27">>
with id <70029939309000>.
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get the forward and backward pointers to point the same objects?  This is being particularly important to me because I'm trying to modify both objects simultaneously and validating the changes, but the bar.foo linkage isn't seeing changes to the "parent" foo object so my validations are failing during the tests.

Alas, after searching for a few hours I trying many different approaches I have not been able to figure this one out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: activerecord doesn't have an identity map.

Long version: when you load the same database row in 2 places you end up with 2 separate objects. When compared with == they are the same (since active record defines thus to just compare the id columns), but they are not the same when using `equal?`. (`assert_equal` used == last time I used test/unit though).

In the specific case where you're doing something like `bar.foos.first.bar` you can specify the `inverse_of` option on the associations tells rails that 2 associations are the opposite of each other.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be close to what I want, except for one detail:

There are limitations to :inverse_of support:
* for belongs_to associations has_many inverse associations are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

short answer:
  1. (it seems) fixture doesn't understand the 'reference', it only knows the 'column names'. 
  2. assign the `id` in fixture sometimes is not a bad idea

so, change your fixtures as below:

```
# foos.yml
one: 
  id: 1

# bars.yml
one:
  id: 1       # always assign the id
  foo_id: 1   # don't use:  foo: one
```

if you don't like fixture, or your object associations is complicated, switch to 'FactoryGirl' (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work (I just tested it).  The fixtures DO understand the references. The objects are equivalent but not the same.  I.e., assert_equal returns true, but assert_same returns an error.  (This was true before when I used references, and it's true when I use id numbers)